# Could we have "all questions" in the navigation button bar bit more clear?

Tags: feature-request, design

Navigate to, let's say [**Unanswered C questions**](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/c) and see this:

[image]

Which one to choose to get back to all questions only tagged by the C tag is not clear at this time. There's quite enough space to play with, so can't we have some graphical hierarchy there? I don't know, maybe something like this might help my brain to understand:

[image]

I think that if you put the left link to all questions (no matter what tag they have) to top, it might be more clear.

Comment: Perhaps the one on the right could read "all `[c]` questions"

Comment: No wait forget that that's a horrible idea for longer tag names. "all [firebase-analytics] questions" is going to look really bad

Comment: @DavyM, that could overlap. `[c]` is the shortest possible name of the tag. Yet, there's enough space for categorization.

Comment: Yes indeed... What a design output. I know they just pilled up layouts and it ended up like this... But it makes me want to throw myself out the window every time.

Comment: @Antoine, I feel something similar. It's the 21st century, and I was even taught that the whole site probably needs to be reloaded (including the top and left navigation bars) to refresh the content in the middle when you click some of that brand new left bar buttons (which I disabled). My live lost sense at that time :)